# Frame of header view changed forever after deletion of UITableView's section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I'm reusing headers, keeping them in dictionary where section number is key and header view is value.

After I animated deleted one section and reload another one, header views of only these sections "disappeared". After some searching, I found that frames of these header view was changed. `Frame.X` of header view from section that was deleted with `UITableViewRowAnimationRight` shifter to right by screen width (320), and the one that was realoaded with `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` shifted by `Y`.

The main problem and confusion comes from the fact that I'm unable to change these frames! Well, they change at first, but nothing changes visually and on the other call of `viewForHeaderInSection:` frames are shifted again.

Here is how I do that:

Assume we have 3 section, with data of each lays in one of arrays `_first`, `_second` and `_third`. And by button's touchupinside we call `handleTouchUp:`. (`_second` remains unchanged)

```
- (void) handleTouchUp: (UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([_first count] == 0) {
        sectionCount = 3;
        _first = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"First 1", @"First 2", nil];
        _third = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Third 1", @"Third 2", @"Third 3", @"Third 4", @"Third 5", nil];
        [tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        sectionCount = 2;
        [_first removeAllObjects];
        _third = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"First 1", @"First 2", @"Third 1", @"Third 2",
                                                   @"Third 3", @"Third 4", @"Third 5", nil];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [tableView reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: section];
    UIView *header = [_headers objectForKey: key];
    if (header) {

    } else {
        header = [[UIView alloc] init];
        switch (section) {
            //Doing something with header here (e.g. set background color)
        }
        [_headers setObject:header forKey: key];
    }

    [header setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 25)];

    return header;
}
```

[Here is full code of ViewController.m](http://pastie.org/8018139) and [test project](http://rghost.net/46572457)

**UPDATE:**
There may be some other errors in project, but it's not important -- it's test project. The only important problem is invalid header views. Removing invalid view and creating the new one isn't the solution -- it kills the point of reusing header views.

Answer (score 3):

I found several mistakes in your project which actually led to some crashes and I believe they were also responsible to the header view bugs you were seeing in the app. 
After I fixed those and the application seems to function properly to me.

Here is an updated version of your project: https://bitbucket.org/reydan/tableheaderviews

I tried to keep it as similar as possible to your initial project, but I had to make some changes. If you believe it does not match your desired functionality, leave a comment and I will update (This is what I deduced that the project should behave like)
All changes that are explained below, can also be seen in this updated project.

The problems I found were related to the fact that if you delete a section from a table view, all the section after it will have their index changed (with -1). This is normal, because section index is really an index and not an unique key assigned to each section.

After you removed the first section , the third section now had index = 1 and the table view delegate methods read data incorrectly (including header views) since you had everything based on the section index.

To fix this, I changed the header view cache to use the data arrays as keys (_first, _second or _third).
To make this easier, I created a method which can called from multiple places and returns the correct data array based on the section index and current section count:

```
- (NSArray*)dataArrayForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (sectionCount == 3)
    {
        switch (section)
        {
            case 0: return _first;
            case 1: return _second;
            case 2: return _third;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (section)
        {
            case 0: return _second;
            case 1: return _third;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Now that the header cache uses the data arrays as keys, it is important to remove the header entries when reallocating the arrays in the `handleTouchUp` method.

```
- (void) handleTouchUp: (UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Touched!");
    if ([_first count] == 0)
    {
        sectionCount = 3;

        // **INSERTED** Removes the cache for the _first and _third keys because you are recreating the arrays again,
        // and so you are losing the initial key. Not doing this, results in a memory leak
        [_headers removeObjectForKey:_first];
        [_headers removeObjectForKey:_third];

        _first = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"First 1", @"First 2", nil];
        _third = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Third 1", @"Third 2", @"Third 3", @"Third 4", @"Third 5", nil];

        [tableView reloadData];
//        [tableView beginUpdates];
//        [tableView reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
//        [tableView reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
//        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
    else
```

Another thing I improved is reusing the table view cells. You should always try and reuse existing UITableViewCells (with few exceptions). The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` now looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray* dataarray = [self dataArrayForSection:indexPath.section];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"my_text_cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"my_text_cell"];


    if (dataarray == nil)
        cell.textLabel.text = @"default";
    else
        cell.textLabel.text = [dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

If you have any questions, please leave a comment.

**EDIT**

I tried to update my test project as you requested, to keep the cache intact and I was indeed able to reproduce the bug - after the delete/reload animation, the header for the last section is not visible.

What I discovered is that the Automatic reload animation iOS chooses is the Fade animation.
This causes the header view to fade out. I tested this by adding another button in the app that sets alpha=1 for all cached header views. After the reload animation, I pressed this button and the header views appeared correctly.

I tried using other animations, but they didn't look nice.

In the end, I don't think Apple recommends caching header views. In the documentation , starting with iOS 6.0 there is a new method that addresses this issue. It behaves similar to dequeueing cells, but for header/footer views
`- (id)dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

So, if you target iOS 6.0+  then you can use this instead of manually caching the headers. Otherwise, the solution I found is to remove from cache only the header views for the deleted and reloaded sections (_first and _third).

I updated the project to remove only the last section header when refreshing

Comment: The point was that header view's frame becomes invalid after animated deletion/reload. All other errors (including reusing cells) doesn't really matter because it's just test project that I wrote to show the problem with header view frames. Reason why your project doesn't have this issue is that you're always recreating header views that was affected by animations and not doing that was the whole point of header view "cache". Also I didn't get your comment about loosing initial key (just before removing header from cache).

Comment: But anyway, header view shouldn't be broken after animation, that's just wrong. If I want to use the very same-looking view, I should be able to use exact the same view if it isn't broken and if that view shows one time in view hierarchy. If you could, please try not to clear cache, and you will end up with broken views.

Comment: I'll try and explain better what I mean by wrong keys. You have cached header views for keys 0,1,2. When you delete the first section (index=0) and refresh the section 2, that refresh will be called with index=1 - because the first section disappeared and all other sections shifted with -1. So, in that header refresh, based on your code you will return the header view with key 1, but that exact uiview is also used for the previous second section (which was not refreshed and it kept the old  header view).  Having the same UIView in 2 places I believe causes problems.

Comment: My project can work without refreshing the header cache, but in that case you will need to NOT reallocate the the _first, _second and _third arrays. You can change their contents, but not reallocate them - since they are used as keys for headers. If you want, I can update my project to reflect this.

Comment: Though your answer took a lot of effort, it's not a solution :(

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it is not a solution, but sometimes you have to do it the apple way :).  Why is it that you really wish to cache the header views? Are they that complicated?

Comment: I've used to do that for any custom headers, because every ms of main thread time costs a lot. And such behavior (I'd rather said "bug") was surprise for me.